# SSH access to GitHub inside of GitHub Action runner (macOS)

Tags: git, macos, npm, github-actions

It is not a self-hosted runner.

I am trying to build an auto-deploy workflow on GitHub Action. But one of my packages is based on a private repo of mine, and whenever I run `npm i` this error will show:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepo.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! remote: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepo.git/' not found
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-04-22T21_31_16_860Z-debug.log
```

I found a workaround by using `pioug/la-cle@v1.1.0` with my SSH key, but it only works for `npm ci` and cannot help when the project needs to check the dependencies inside other commands. For example, the error shows above also shows when I run `ionic cordova platform remove ios` after that action is applied. So I would need a general solution.

UPDATE: After a brief view on `la-cle`, I think it is creating an ssh setting for the GitHub Action runner. I have no idea why it is not working for my case at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the issue of not using SSH connection on that private repo dependency.

After switching it from `git+https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepo.git/` to `git+ssh@github.com:MyUsername/MyRepo.git/` the problem is solved.